# Make a density list plot/histogram from large, pre-binned data set?

Tags: plotting, histograms

I have a large data set consisting of $\mathcal{O}(10^9)$ two-dimensional points.  In order to save memory and time I have pre-binned these into a uniform grid of $500 \times 500$ bins using Fortran.  When imported into Mathematica 8.0 as a table the resulting data look like:

> `data = {{0.388348, 0.388349, 9},{0.388348, 0.776699, 23},...}`,

where the first two items of each entry correspond to the $x$-$y$-coordinates of the upper-right-hand corner of the bin and the third is the count.

### Edit:

- For a sample of the raw data, `raw=RandomReal[1,{1000000000,2}]` is a good approximation.  This is obviously unworkable.
- For the binned data: `binned=Table[{.01*Ceiling[raw[[i,1]]/.01],.01*Ceiling[raw[[i,2]]/.01],RandomInteger[1000]},{i,1,250000}]`.

I would like to plot this pre-binned data set in the form of a DensityHistogram, but my data format doesn't fit into what this function is expecting.  I have reviewed a similar question for one-dimensional histograms at [Histograms with pre-counted data](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3981/histograms-with-pre-counted-data), however I'm at a loss as to how to apply this to 2-D.  I have also looked at doing

> `Image[Rescale[data]]`

on the raw data.  However, this crashes immediately with a SIGSEGV error that has the Wolfram Support team puzzled.  Consequently, I haven't gone very far down this road.

### Edit:

- I have also tried `ListDensityPlot[data,InterpolationOrder->0]`.  For the full data set, Mathematica hangs for over 10 minutes, at which point it runs out of memory and the kernel shuts down.  For a subset of the data, I get something more reasonable, but I would need some way to scale this up to $500^2$ data points.

Making these plots seem to be something that is fairly easily done in Matplotlib, but I have already made some other plots in Mathematica and don't want to mess with different styles.  I'm fairly new to Mathematica and don't have a good knowledge of all the functionality, unfortunately.

So, how can I make a DensityHistogram when the bins and counts have already been calculated?

Comment: `ListPlot3D[data, InterpolationOrder -> 0, Filling -> Bottom, 
 Mesh -> None]` - can you try this and tell me what you see? BTW, welcome to MSE! Also can you upload somewhere your *binned* and *original* data sets and provide a link?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov--With the $\mathcal{O}(500^2)$ binned set, this ran out of memory. With 1000 points it gave me a 3D plot with the $z$-axis as the count number. I would need a flat, 2D plot that is similar to DensityHistogram.  The binned data looks like what I have given above, just $500^2$ of them, and the unbinned data looks similar to just the first two items in each entry.

Comment: `ListDensityPlot[data, ColorFunction -> "SouthwestColors"]` - then try this and let us know the result.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov--This was what I tried first, actually. I really need two things: 1) no or very little interpolation and 2) the full $500^2$ data set plotted. With a simple ListDensityPlot Mathematica just hangs forever (10+ minutes) and I'm too impatient to see what the results are.  With a truncated data set I get a washed-out density plot that loses sight of substructure.  With `InterpolationOrder->0` it's starting to resemble what I want, but the plotting time is still very slow.

Comment: what about uniform binning? `binned = BinCounts[raw, {0, 1, 1/100.}, {0, 1, 1/100.}]*1.; binned /= 
 Max[binned];
binned // Image`; it works for 10^8 points in about 20 seconds

Comment: @chris--This is very close. I'm running into some memory problems when doing BinCounts on the full data set, but I'm able to extract this information from the bin counting I have already done in Fortran. How can I go about now superimposing some axes and ticks onto the image?

Comment: I found [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7552/plotting-large-datasets), which seems to have an answer for putting ticks on the image.

Comment: @cosmoguy Wouldn't you want Image[Rescale[data[[All,All,3]]]?

Comment: Do you really need a density plot? Cannot you just use a ListContourPlot[]? IMHO, this looks much clearer and you can really see the pattern. What is more, you can also output a color-bar and use many more other features...

Comment: @s0rce--The binned data is stored as an $N \times 3$ table, so data[[All,All,3]] is undefined.  Substituting data[[All,3]], though, gives an error when doing Image: The specified argument ... should be an array of rank 2 or 3 with machine-sized numbers.

Comment: @AnastasiiaAnishchenko--A ListContourPlot is not ideal when the data has fine substructure as the contour borders obscure the image. A color-bar is very interesting, however, and is something I would like to implement, if possible, from chris' suggestion above.

Comment: @chris--I have used your suggestion.  If you want to write it up, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 15):

You may be able to use the new `WeightedData` in version 9 with `HistogramDistribution` to create a weighted histogram. I've reduced the number of points for speed but it should hopefully scale to your actual problem.

```
raw = RandomReal[1, {10000000, 2}];

binned = Table[{.01*Ceiling[raw[[i, 1]]/.01], .01*
     Ceiling[raw[[i, 2]]/.01], RandomInteger[1000]}, {i, 1, 25000}];
```

Now I create the `WeightedData` using your bin counts and fit a `HistogramDistribution` to them. Note that you can set a different binning if you choose but I'm using the automatic binning.

```
wd = WeightedData[binned[[All, 1 ;; 2]], binned[[All, 3]]];

hd = HistogramDistribution[wd];
```

Now to use `DensityPlot` to visualize the `PDF`.

```
DensityPlot[PDF[hd, {x, y}], {x, 0.01, 1}, {y, 0.01, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None, PlotPoints -> 50, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]