# Generating 250 random points crashes the kernel, but not 249

Tags: bugs, list-manipulation, random, crash

**Fixed in 10.1.0.**

Consider the following function, which generates uniformly random points on the surface of the 2-sphere:

```
randSphere[] := Block[{z = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]},
    If[Total[z^2] > 1, randSphere[], Normalize[z]]]
```

I can use this function to generate a `Table` of 249 points:

```
Table[randSphere[], {249}] (* works fine *)
```

but mysteriously, changing 249 to 250 consistently crashes the kernel. I am running Mathematica 10.0.2 on Windows. What's going on here? It's worth noting that I can also generate 249 *pairs* of points with no problems:

```
Table[{randSphere[], randSphere[]}, {249}] (* also works fine *)
```

and I can even generate 249 `Table`s of 249 points:

```
Table[Table[randSphere[], {249}], {249}] (* still fine *)
```

but changing any instance of 249 to 250 in each of the above examples crashes the kernel again.

Comment: Reproduced in 10.0.2 OS X.  `Table` will attempt to auto-compile its first argument starting at 250, which is certainly related to the crash.  The `CompileOptions` setting from `SystemOptions` controls this.

Comment: Reproduced in v9.0.1 as well.  This crash is almost certainly related to the recursive call in `randSphere`.  The workaround is to get rid of that (use a `While[... > 1, (* recompute *)]` sort of thing).  `Compile` doesn't support recursive calls.  I'm tagging this as a bug, please report it to `support` at `wolfram.com`.

Comment: @Szabolcs Interesting. I've never heard of this compiling behavior before; is it documented anywhere? The docs for `Table` don't mention anything special about `250`.

Comment: It probably isn't documented, I'm not sure.  It's often discussed on Mathematica forums though, so it's "common knowledge" in the community.  Try `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "TableCompileLength" -> 300]` to set it to 300.  I don't mean this as a workaround though.

Comment: You can get all default compile lengths by evaluating `SystemOptions["CompileOptions"]`.

Comment: For other methods of generating random points on a sphere, you may be interested in this Q&A: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13038/vectors-with-a-certain-magnitude-in-mathematica

Comment: Note also that `Compile[{}, randSphere[]]` itself crashes my kernel (V10.0.1 Mac OSX 10.9.5).  I'm not sure of the relation to the OP's problem, since autocompile might do a different command.

Comment: Reported as a bug.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Your simpler example indeed runs afoul of the same underlying problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 By the way, your formulation will have a separate but possibly related issue in that the (weak) type inferencing mechanism in `Compile` will not know what is getting returned. The variant below makes this explicit, and has the pleasant side effect of circumventing the crash.`ff = Compile[{}, randSphere[], {{_randSphere,_Real,1}}]; Table[ff[],{250}]` I do not understand how this manages to evade the crash. Which is weird, since I now know what causes said crash. One of those mysteries.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I can reproduce this on OS X in M10.0.2 and M9.0.1, so it looks like a bug.  Please report it to Wolfram support.

`Table` will automatically try to compile its argument above a table length threshold.  This threshold is 250 by default and can be set to a different value using `SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions" -> "TableCompileLength" -> ...]`.  It seems the crash happens only when `Table` compiles its argument.

The `randSphere` function is recursive but `Compile` doesn't support recursion.  My *guess* is that the crash is related to this.

I recommend eliminating the recursion as a workaround:

```
randSphere[] := Module[{z},
  While[True,
   z = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3];
   If[Total[z^2] <= 1, Return@Normalize[z]]
   ]
  ]
```

This version won't crash.

Comment: We are aware of this issue. I don't have an ETA for when it will be fixed, though.

Comment: @StefanR Out of curiosity, is the problem really related to the recursion?

Comment: Yes, it's related to the recursion. Not the actual running of the recursion, but in the preprocessing.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you can use the following function to generate pseudo-random points on the sphere:

```
PointOnTwoSphere[] := Module[
  {z, phi, rho, x, y},
  z = RandomReal[{-1, 1}];
  phi = RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}];
  rho = Sqrt[1 - z^2];
  x = rho * Cos[phi];
  y = rho * Sin[phi];
  {x, y, z}
]
```

This algorithm, due to [Marsaglia](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/aoms/1177692644),
has the virtue that it does not throw away any points.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution but worth noting.

[image]
[image]

```
ParallelTable[randSphere[], {250}]
```

Does seem to work.

I dont know about its limit, but eventually, it crashed (as expected for "big" data).
[image]