# Issue with casting a set of random points on a cylinder surface

Tags: graphics3d, random, geometry

Code:

```
    (*Cylinder Point Picking*)
    ppCylinder[p1_List, p2_List, radius_Integer, expNo_Integer] :=
              Module[
                    {pts},
                    (*Set point coordinates *)
                    pts := Point[Table[{radius*Cos[#1], radius*Sin[#1], #2} &[RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}], RandomReal[{p1[[3]], p2[[3]]}]], {expNo}]];

                    (*Visualize*)
                    Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{p1, p2}, radius], pts}, Boxed -> False]
    ];

    (*Test*)
    ppCylinder[{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, 2, 5000] (*Output #1*)
    ppCylinder[{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2}, 2, 5000] (*Output #2*)
```

Output 1:
[image: Output 1]

Output 2:
[image: Output 2]

Based on the code I wrote, I am satisfied with the output 1# but not #2. How could I modify the existing code to account for {X && Y} variation when generating a set of random points on a cylinder surface?

Comment: I left a comment showing a faster method for generating points on the surface of a cylinder in your previous question. Did you see it?

Comment: Notice in your code that you only ever used the z-coordinate of `p1` and `p2` to generate the points.

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for your comment. Yes, I did see it. The reason why I haven't used it is due to my inability to fully comprehend the implementation. Therefore I decided to stick to what I had implemented initially. But it has a flow. Therefore I have started a new question on the topic.

Comment: In that case, you'll want to see [this related topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13038).

Comment: I also realised just now that I have the same type of an issue with my Sphere Point Picking model -.-, which I hope I can fix using similar approaches described below

Comment: With the sphere, it's easier, since it's rotationally invariant. Only a translation is needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to transform the generated points (which currently lie on a cylinder that's aligned with the $z$-axis) so that they lie on the new cylinder. You can accomplish this with a [`TranslationTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TranslationTransform.html) followed by a [`RotationTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationTransform.html):

```
ppCylinder[p1_List, p2_List, radius_Integer, expNo_Integer] :=
  With[{
    (* the height of the cylinder isn't just the difference of the
       z coordinates! *)
    height = Norm[p2 - p1], 
    transform = 
      TranslationTransform[p1] @* RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, p2 - p1}]},
   Module[{pts},
    pts := Point[
     Table[transform@{radius*Cos[#1], radius*Sin[#1], #2} &[
       RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}], RandomReal[{0, height}]], {expNo}]];
     (*Visualize*)
    Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{p1, p2}, radius], pts}, Boxed -> False]]];
```

Now `ppCylinder[{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, 2, 5000]` returns:

[image]

Comment: OP's examples all use the origin as the first point, but if the first point is an argument to the function, you should be able to make it anything.  Try `ppCylinder[{6, 0, 4}, {0, 1, 2}, 2, 5000]` to see an unexpected result.

Comment: @Jason, that would be on account of transformations not being commutative with respect to composition.

Comment: @J.M., yeah, I thought I had the order right, but no such luck. Fix'd.

Answer (score 4):

Since Pillsy's already hit on the important issue of doing the proper rotation + translation, I'll just leave this normal distribution-based method for generating random points on a cylinder:

```
ppCylinder[p1_?VectorQ, p2_?VectorQ, r_?Positive, n_Integer?Positive, opts___] :=
           Module[{h = EuclideanDistance[p1, p2], rt, pts},
                  rt = RotationTransform[{{0, 0, 1}, p2 - p1}]; 
                  pts = Point[Table[Composition[TranslationTransform[p1], rt] @
                  Append[r Normalize[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 2]],
                         RandomReal[h]],
                  {n}]];

                  Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{p1, p2}, r], pts}, opts, Boxed -> False]]
```

Generating normal variates can be more efficient than generating uniform variates and then applying trigonometric functions on them.

Test:

```
ppCylinder[{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2}, 2, 1*^4]
```

[image: points on a cylinder]

---

Here is a faster implementation that eschews the use of `Table[]` and uses the second argument of `RandomReal[]`/`RandomVariate[]` to generate many points at once:

```
ppCylinder[p1_?VectorQ, p2_?VectorQ, r_?Positive, n_Integer?Positive, opts___] :=
           Module[{h = EuclideanDistance[p1, p2], pts, tr},
                  tr = AffineTransform[{RotationMatrix[{{0, 0, 1}, p2 - p1}], p1}];
                  pts = MapThread[Composition[tr, Append],
                                  {r (Normalize /@
                                      RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, 2}]),
                                   RandomReal[h, n]}];
                  Graphics3D[{Cylinder[{p1, p2}, r], Point[pts]},
                             opts, Boxed -> False]]
```

This is ~ 10 times faster than the previous implementation in my tests.

Comment: If the speed of execution matters, this method is much slower than Pillsy's method.  If I modify his function as I mention in the comment above, and then execute the resulting function on `ppCylinder[{5, 4, 2}, {-7, 1, 2}, 2, 5000]` it takes about 0.15 seconds.  But the same test on your function takes almost 6 seconds.  I don't know what the slowdown step is though.

Comment: That would be because I used a `Table[]` as opposed to generating the random points all at once. (I wanted the routine to have some resemblance to the OP's code, since he said he was not familiar with the normal distribution approach.) I'll include the faster method in a little while.