# How to define a set of two random orthogonal unit vectors?

Tags: random, vector

I need to define a random set of two orthogonal unit vectors.  The code below doesn't give proper unit and orthogonal vectors :

```
Clear["Global`*"]

n[k_] := Normalize[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}]

u[k_] := Normalize[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}]

a[k_] := Normalize[u[k] - (u[k].n[k])n[k]]

(* unitary and orthogonality test : *)
Table[n[k].n[k], {k, 1, 5}]  (* this should output five 1 *)
Table[a[k].a[k], {k, 1, 5}]  (* this should output five 1 *)
Table[n[k].a[k], {k, 1, 5}]  (* this should output five 0 *)
```

Specifically, for any value of $k$ (which should be any real number) :
\begin{align}
    \vec{\boldsymbol{n}}(k) \cdot \vec{\boldsymbol{n}}(k) &= 1, \\
    \vec{\boldsymbol{a}}(k) \cdot \vec{\boldsymbol{a}}(k) &= 1. \\
    \vec{\boldsymbol{n}}(k) \cdot \vec{\boldsymbol{a}}(k) &= 0.
\end{align}

So what is wrong with the code above ?

Comment: `n[k_]:=` defines a function of `k`. If you call it 3 times with the same argument, it gets evaluated 3 times and you get 3 different random vectors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As nikie pointed out, the issue is that each time you call one of your functions (regardless of `k`) new random vectors will be calculated. A quick fix for this is to memoise the functions. That means they'll be assigned a random value the first time they are called, but will then remember that value for the given `k` and always return the same. Memoisation is trivial in Mathematica:

```
n[k_] := n[k] = Normalize[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}]
u[k_] := u[k] = Normalize[{RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}], RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}]
a[k_] := a[k] = Normalize[u[k] - (u[k].n[k]) n[k]]

Table[n[k].n[k], {k, 1, 5}]
Table[a[k].a[k], {k, 1, 5}]
Table[n[k].a[k], {k, 1, 5}]

(* {1., 1., 1., 1., 1.} *)
(* {1., 1., 1., 1., 1.} *)
(* {9.4369*10^-16, 2.77556*10^-17, 5.55112*10^-17, 0., 5.55112*10^-17} *)
```

Note that the slight discrepancies from zero are due to floating point inaccuracies. These are unavoidable due to the finite representation of "real" numbers in computers. I recommend that you give [the floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) a thorough read. If you're feeling brave you can also read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), but it's a lot more technical.

When working with floats, you should always check that your results fall into a narrow band of tolerance (e.g. $10^{-10}$) of the desired value and never use exact equality.

---

As for your actual implementation, `n` and `u` can be simplified by generating a random vector right away:

```
n[k_] := n[k] = Normalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]]
u[k_] := u[k] = Normalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]]
```

Alternatively, you can use `Orthogonalize`, where now `a` and `b` are your orthonormal vectors, but note that the memoisation gets a bit trickier, since you're generating two corresponding vectors when either one is requested:

```
a[k_] := First[{a[k], b[k]} = Orthogonalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 3}]]]
b[k_] := Last[{a[k], b[k]} = Orthogonalize[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, 3}]]]

Table[a[k].a[k], {k, 1, 5}]
Table[b[k].b[k], {k, 1, 5}]
Table[a[k].b[k], {k, 1, 5}]
(* {1., 1., 1., 1., 1.} *)
(* {1., 1., 1., 1., 1.} *)
(* {0., 0., 3.46945*10^-17, 5.55112*10^-17, -5.55112*10^-17} *)
```

Also, you should note that this method (as well as your original method) will not create vectors which are uniformly distributed over the sphere. The vectors you get from `Normalize[RandomReal[{-1,1},3]]` will be less commonly aligned with the axes and more commonly point along the diagonals of the space. If you want to ensure a uniform distribution of these vectors, you'll have to do something more clever (rejection sampling, or using a weighted distribution in spherical polar coordinates maybe). I am also not sure whether a uniform distribution of input vectors will result in a uniform distribution of planes spanned by the two orthogonal vectors you end up with, although it seems likely on grounds of symmetry.

Comment: A simple question :  Is this code the best (proper or simplest) way to define random orthogonal unit vectors ?  Or is there a better way of doing this with Mathematica ?

Comment: @Cham You can definitely simplify `n` and `u` with `RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]` to get a random vector. I'll edit the answer in a bit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Martin (same first name as me, ;-) ) !

Comment: About the random unit vector uniformly distributed on a sphere, I would simply use `n = {Sqrt[1 - u^2]Cos[phi], Sqrt[1 - u^2]Sin[phi], u}`, with `u = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]` and `phi = RandomReal[{0, 2Pi}]`.  This is automatically uniformly distributed on a sphere.  So no complicated rejection code.

Comment: In the case of the vector $\vec{a}$, I would use some easy rotation matrices.  We have $\vec{n} = R_z(\phi) R_y(\theta) \hat{z}$.  The orthogonal vector is then defined as this : $\vec{a}(\alpha) = R_z(\phi) R_y(\theta) R_z(\alpha) \hat{x}$, where $\alpha$ is a random angle uniformly distributed on $(0, \, 2 \pi)$.  It is easy to show that $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{n} \equiv 0$, for all angles $\alpha$.  I'll then use the random variable $u = \cos{\theta}$ and $\sqrt{1 - u^2} = \sin{\theta}$.

Comment: [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13038/vectors-with-a-certain-magnitude-in-mathematica) addresses methods of choosing vectors on a sphere with a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 3):

```
(*Function*)
nal[k_Integer?Positive] := 
 RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{{0, \[Pi]}, {-\[Pi], \[Pi]}}], 
       2 k] // Map@Prepend[1] // 
     CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", #] & // 
    Partition[#, 2] & // Map@Orthogonalize // Transpose

(*Use*)
{nl, al} = nal[5]
Norm /@ nl
Norm /@ al
MapThread[Dot, {nl, al}] // Chop

(*Or*)
Clear[n, a]
Evaluate@{Array[n, 5], Array[a, 5]} = nal[5]
Table[n[k].n[k], {k, 1, 5}]
Table[a[k].a[k], {k, 1, 5}]
Table[n[k].a[k], {k, 1, 5}] // Chop
```

Results

```
{{{-0.825575, 0.22288, 0.518411}, {0.128707, 0.483466, 
   0.865849}, {0.959535, -0.178934, 0.21743}, {0.780066, -0.574996, 
   0.24673}, {-0.921722, 0.0682483, 0.3818}}, {{0.48972, -0.173447, 
   0.854453}, {0.0995755, 0.862398, -0.496341}, {-0.220525, 
   0.00265385, 0.975378}, {0.302404, 
   0.00124804, -0.953179}, {-0.28588, 0.545705, -0.787704}}}

{1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}

{1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}

{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

{{{-0.50804, 0.653068, 0.561602}, {0.625118, -0.315714, 
   0.71383}, {0.748392, -0.629871, 
   0.207781}, {0.382584, -0.0387238, -0.923109}, {0.0835878, 
   0.288501, -0.953824}}, {{-0.370342, -0.754291, 
   0.542118}, {-0.135175, 0.856936, 0.497382}, {0.335259, 
   0.0889442, -0.937918}, {-0.918986, -0.119072, -0.375881}, \
{0.685458, -0.711399, -0.155105}}}

{1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}

{1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}

{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

another simple way to get *uniformly distributed* vectors, by rejecting random vectors that fall outside a unit sphere:

```
randv := Module[{v}, 
  Normalize[While@(Norm[v = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3]] > 1); v]]
rs = Table[Orthogonalize[{randv, randv}], {500}];
Norm /@ rs[[All, 1]] // Union  (*1.*)
Norm /@ rs[[All, 2]] // Union  (*1.*)
Dot @@ # & /@ rs // Chop // Union (*0.*)
```

Answer (score 1):

Any of the above "solutions" that is based on uniformly sampling a unit cube and simply projecting a point onto a sphere will not give a uniform random pair of orthogonal vectors.  That is because the projection does not *uniformly* sample the sphere.  You can see that by looking at the cluster of points on the unit sphere close to the corners of the cube in this figure:

```
Graphics3D[{
  {Opacity[0.5], Sphere[]},
  Point[Normalize /@ RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {50000, 3}]]
  }]
```

Instead, one should sample from a spherical Gaussian distribution, which has no such preferred directions.

This code (truly) randomly selects a direction from the unit sphere, rotates each of the two unit orthogonal basis vector by a random angle $0 \le \theta \leq 2 \pi$ around that direction.

```
u = {1, 0, 0}; 
v = {0, 1, 0};
orthogonalvectors = Orthogonalize@(RotationMatrix[
       RandomReal[{0, 2 π}], 
       RandomVariate[
        MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, 
         IdentityMatrix[3]]]].# & /@ {u, v})
```

(*
{{0.988191, -0.112487, -0.104045}, {-0.0381163, 0.477218, -0.877958}}
*)

Confirm by:

```
ortogonalvectors[[1]].ortogonalvectors[[1]] //Chop
```

(* 1 *)

```
ortogonalvectors[[2]].ortogonalvectors[[2]] //Chop
```

(* 1 *)

```
ortogonalvectors[[1]].ortogonalvectors[[2]] //Chop
```

(* 0 *)

Run the code as often as you like to get new pairs of orthogonal vectors.

Compare closely the above sphere figure with this one that properly samples the unit sphere:

```
Graphics3D[{
  {Opacity[0.5], Sphere[]},
  Red, Point[
   Normalize /@ 
    RandomVariate[
     MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0, 0}, IdentityMatrix[3]], 5000]]
  }]
```

Comment: This solution appears to be a bit similar to the one I've adopted, that I posted above.  However, I don't use any gaussian distribution.

Comment: @Cham, the point is that the normal distribution is the **right** distribution to use for uniformly sampling a sphere. Certainly cheaper than evaluating trig functions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I've adopted :

```
(* Uniformly distributed random values of Cos[theta] : *)
u[k_] := u[k] = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]

(* Uniformly distributed random value of phi : *)
phi[k_] := phi[k] = RandomReal[{0, 2Pi}]

(* Random unit vector : *)
n[k_] := n[k] = {
        Sqrt[1 - u[k]^2]Cos[phi[k]],
        Sqrt[1 - u[k]^2]Sin[phi[k]],
        u[k]
    }

(* Uniformly distributed random angle AROUND the vector n[k] : *)
alpha[k_] := alpha[k] = RandomReal[{0, 2Pi}]

(* Random unit vector, orthogonal to n[k] by construction : *)
a[k_] := a[k] = {
        u[k]Cos[alpha[k]]Cos[phi[k]] - Sin[alpha[k]]Sin[phi[k]],
        u[k]Cos[alpha[k]]Sin[phi[k]] + Sin[alpha[k]]Cos[phi[k]],
        -Sqrt[1 - u[k]^2]Cos[alpha[k]]
    }
```

Here's a plot of 5000 points from the `n[k]` vector (in red), and 5000 points from the `a[k]`vector (in blue) :

[image: random points on a sphere]

Code to plot this picture :

```
Graphics3D[
    Table[
    {
        {Red,  PointSize -> 0.003, Point[n[k]]},
        {Blue, PointSize -> 0.003, Point[a[k]]}
    }, {k, 1, 5000}], 
SphericalRegion -> True,
Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
ImageSize -> {600, 600}
]
```

Is there any drawback to this method ?