# How do you plot random points in three dimensions?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I've got a function that maps a 2D plane onto a sphere (I'm trying to learn about Geodesics).

```
f[u_,v_]:={X[u,v],Y[u,v],Z[u,v]};
X[u_,v_]:=Cos[v]Sin[u];
Y[u_,v_]:=Sin[v]Sin[u];
Z[u_,v_]:=Cos[u];
```

I want to plot this, but the Plot3D gives me only a single value for any given [X,Y] set of coordinates.  At the least, I'd like something like a scatter chart (that is, just give it 3 coordinates and have it plot a point), but it would be nice to be able to generate a wire-frame so I could draw my solutions.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13038)

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[u_, v_] := {X[u, v], Y[u, v], Z[u, v]};
X[u_, v_] := Cos[v] Sin[u];
Y[u_, v_] := Sin[v] Sin[u];
Z[u_, v_] := Cos[u];

SeedRandom[1234]

data = f @@@ RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, {5000, 2}];

Graphics3D[Point[data]]
```

[image]

However, you can get a smoother distribution with [`RandomPoint`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html) on a [`Sphere`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sphere.html)

```
SeedRandom[1234]

data2 = RandomPoint[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}], 5000];

Graphics3D[Point[data2]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Converting the points into a 3-D surface

```
ListSurfacePlot3D[data2, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Your first approach is not correct. Pay your attention that the points flock near the poles.

Comment: @user64494 it's not incorrect — it's just a different distribution.

Comment: Great answer.  Thank you.  For extra points, can you make that into a wire-frame?

Comment: @Ruslan: Exactly saying, the points produced by the first code are not uniformly distributed on the sphere so these can't be called random points on the sphere.

Comment: @user64494 random doesn't imply uniform.

Comment: @user64494 - The OP did not specify that the points in the "scatter chart" should be uniformly distributed on the sphere. The first approach demonstrates that if you start with a uniform distribution in 2-D, the transformation does not produce a uniform distribution in 3-D. While [`RandomPoint[reg, n]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomPoint.html) gives a list of `n` pseudorandom points uniformly distributed in the region `reg`; if you were to transform these 3-D points on a sphere to 2-D, they would not be uniform in 2-D.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bob Hanlon for his answer.  Using that as a starting point, I was able to work out this, which is what I was really after:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{R[u, v]}, {u, 0, Pi}, {v, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image]