# Correct way to format numbers

Tags: list-manipulation, number-representation, output-formatting

I have defined the following function:

```
randvec[mag_]:= mag Normalize[Table[RandomReal[], {j, 1, 4}]]
```

I would like to format the numbers in the list so that they are 4 d.p. Trying the following:

```
randvec[mag_] := NumberForm[mag Normalize[Table[RandomReal[], {j, 1, modes}]], 4]
```

casts each entry as a string. What is the appropriate way to format the list without changing the type of the entries?

Comment: `randvec[mag_] :=  N@Round[mag Normalize[Table[RandomReal[], {j, 1, 4}]], 1*^-4]`?

Comment: A couple more points. `RandomReal[{0, 1}, modes]` will do the same as your table, but more efficiently. I also wonder if this question dealing with the generation of random vectors with a specified magnitude might be relevant to you: [Vectors with a certain magnitude in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13038/27951).