# 3D heatmap density plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I have a set of data that looks like `{{x1, y1, z1}, {x2, y2, z2}, ...}` so it describes points in 3D space. I want to make a heatmap out of this data. So that points with a high density are shown as a cloud and marked with different colors dependend of the density.

In fact, I want the result of this script just for 3D:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {100, 2}];
SmoothDensityHistogram[data, 0.02, "PDF", ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Mesh -> 0]
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!

Comment: Do you have version 9? Then have a look at [`Image3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Image3D.html)...

Comment: Thank you for answer but nope I use Mathematica 8

Comment: It is a great example!! for me I used the Image3D function of mathematica 9 but my problem is how I can change the dimensions of each voxel using Image3D[] function.

Comment: You should ask a different question, not post your question as an answer.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to plot a distribution that is three dimensional then first you need to form it! `SmoothDensityHistogram` plots a smooth kernel histogram of the values $\{x_i,y_i\}$ but as we have three dimensional data here we need the function called  `SmoothKernelDistribution`!

```
data = RandomReal[1, {1000, 3}];
dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
```

Now you have got the probability distribution with three variables. So we can simply plot the `PDF` as a 3d contour plot using `ContourPlot3D`. Keep in mind that this function is reputed to be little slow.

```
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@PDF[dist, {x, y, z}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}, 
PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 160,
ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.45], Mesh -> None, 
ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, f}, ColorData["Rainbow"][z]], 
AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

To cut through the contours I used the option!

```
RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x < z || z > y]
```

In order to check that the data points density is responsible for the shape of the contours we can use `Graphics3D`

```
pic = Graphics3D[{ColorData["DarkRainbow"][#[[3]]],
PointSize -> Large, Point[#]} & /@ data, Boxed -> False];
Show[con, pic]
```

[image]

BR

**EDIT**

To follow up on the 2D example and get warm colours for higher densities

```
 data = RandomReal[1, {500, 3}];
 dist = SmoothKernelDistribution[data];
 ContourPlot3D[Evaluate@PDF[dist, {x, y, z}], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 {z, -2, 2},PlotRange -> All, Mesh -> None, MaxRecursion -> 0, PlotPoints -> 150, 
  ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.45], Contours -> 5, Mesh -> None,
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, f}, ColorData["Rainbow"][f/Max[data]]], 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y, z},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x < z || z > y]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Can't you use `ListContourPlot3D`, *edit* nevermind, result is horrible.

Comment: Great thank you, that script with the edit exactly does the work! One thing if i combine the Point picture with the contour plot i get the following: http://oi47.tinypic.com/34g7otd.jpg
I marked the area that is excluded of the contour plot but contains some points ...

Comment: @user1936577 please consider to use a simpler user name ;) Now you also need to use same exclusion on your points so that all points are not shown. You can use `Cases` or `Select` to pick the relevant points.

Comment: just changed the name ;) But I want to consider all points in my ContourPlot and now I'm wondering about this area that I marked in the link above

Answer (score 20):

The code below (adapted from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11587/685)) produces an output that is similar to the function `Image3D` that is unfortunately available only for *Mathematica* version 9.

Some random 3D data:

```
data = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {5000, 3}];
```

Here we specify the domain to bin (-3, 3) and the binning resolution:

```
binning = {-3, 3, .5};
```

The actual code to produce the figure:

```
binned = BinCounts[data, binning, binning, binning];
dims = Dimensions@binned;
normbinned = N[binned/Max[binned]];
coordswithdataAll = 
  Table[{normbinned[[x, y, z]], {x, y, z}}, {x, 1, dims[[1]]}, {y, 1, 
    dims[[2]]}, {z, 1, dims[[3]]}];
coordswithdata = 
  Table[Select[coordswithdataAll[[j, i]], #[[1]] != 0 &], {j, 
    dims[[1]]}, {i, dims[[1]]}];
cubes = {ColorData["Rainbow"][#1], Opacity@#1, EdgeForm[], 
    Cuboid@#2} &;
output = ParallelMap[cubes @@ # &, coordswithdata, {3}];
Graphics3D[output, PlotRange -> Transpose[{ConstantArray[1, 3], dims + 1}], 
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: voxels]

Comment: upvote for you :)

Comment: +1 for being much, much faster than Answer 1.