# DensityPlot on spherical surface?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I just checked this example [Construct a Globe Showing All Weather Stations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/example/ConstructAGlobeShowingAllWeatherStations.html). It looks good, but I would like to add a density plot of the stations on the spherical surface.

This can be done with the Texture command but it is just the last step, since we still need to firstly obtain the 2D density plot on a plane that can be used to correctly project on the spherical surface. As far as I know, this is not yet a built-in function of Mathematica 9. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: If you have the data, then the basic idea outlined in this answer should be applicable: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15047/how-to-draw-fractal-images-of-iteration-functions-on-the-riemann-sphere/16900#16900

Comment: That's very useful source beyond my question, Thanks for sharing that with me!

Comment: The key point in that other answer (that is relevant to your question) is that the textures work well on spheres, *if* you start with an image in the correct coordinate system. That point is not really "beyond" your question; I think it's exactly what you need.

Comment: Riemann geometry & Stereographic projection, I will try to look into them in spare time.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11586/685

Comment: This is more closely related to my question. Thank you VLC!