# Create a random polymer chain

Tags: random

I want to create a polymer chain (in 2D) of a given length such that:
1. First monomer is at `{0,0}`
2. All other monomers are in the positive x half-plane
3. The distance between two bonded monomers is `r0`
4. No two non-bonded monomers come closer to each other than `rc` (`rc>r0`)

**Edit:** I found a way to implement these rules:
`r0 FoldList[AngleVector,{0, 0},RandomReal[{-1, 1} ArcCos[rc/(2 r0)], n - 1]]`
However, this solution does not sample all possible configurations, but only a small subset.

Comment: So... a self-avoiding random walk? Did you try searching the site for random walk implementations?

Comment: @J.M.needshelp. It is not exactly a self-avoiding random walk. But I did search for random walk. [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154118/57536) is the closest I got to what I want.

Comment: Your fourth condition sounds like "self-avoiding" to me...

Comment: Yes, it has to be self avoiding. But rather than just "not crossing" each other, it has to stay within a certain distance from each other. For example, [this](https://i.imgur.com/Asj2iC0.png) is self-avoiding, but does not satisfy rule 4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This could get you started. As always, we use `Nearest` to determine collision, but put the cheaper collision detection with the left half plane in front. This features also a buffer `reservoir` for future random steps since creating many random numbers at once is usually much more performant.

```
r0 = 0.1;
rc = 0.15;
dim = 2;
maxtrials = 200;
reservoircounter = 1;
chaincounter = 2;
maxchainlength = 10000;
reservoirLength = 1000;
getReservoir[n_, r0_] := RandomPoint[Sphere[ConstantArray[0., dim], r0], n];
chain = ConstantArray[0., {maxchainlength, dim}];
reservoir = getReservoir[reservoirLength, r0];
chain[[2]] = x = chain[[1]] + (# Sign[#[[1]]]) &[RandomPoint[Sphere[ConstantArray[0., dim], r0]]];

chaincounter = 2;
While[chaincounter < maxchainlength,
  nf = Nearest[chain[[1 ;; chaincounter - 1]] -> Automatic];
  ncollisions = 1;
  iter = 0;
  While[ncollisions > 0 && iter < maxtrials,
   reservoircounter++;
   iter++;
   If[reservoircounter > reservoirLength,
    reservoircounter = 1;
    reservoir = getReservoir[reservoirLength, r0];
    ];
   xnew = x + reservoir[[reservoircounter]];
   ncollisions = If[xnew[[1]] >= 0., Length[nf[xnew, {∞, rc}]], 1];
   ];
  If[iter >= maxtrials,
   Break[];
   ,
   chain[[chaincounter + 1]] = x = xnew;
   chaincounter++;
   ]
  ];
```

And some visualization:

```
Graphics[{
  Line[chain[[1 ;; chaincounter]]], Blue, 
  Point[chain[[1 ;; chaincounter]]],
  Red, Opacity[0.15], Disk[#, rc/2] & /@ chain[[1 ;; chaincounter]],
  Darker@Green, PointSize[0.02], Opacity[1], Point[chain[[1]]], 
  Darker@Red, Point[chain[[chaincounter]]]}
 ]
```

[image]

The algorithm can easily be made working for dimension 3 by setting `dim = 3`. This way, one can obtain something like this:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Orange, Specularity[White, 30], 
  Sphere[chain[[1 ;; chaincounter]], rc/2],
  Red, Darker@Green, Sphere[chain[[1]], rc], Darker@Red, 
  Sphere[chain[[chaincounter]], rc],
  }, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks
I will keep the question unanswered for now in case anyone else has a more elegant solution

Comment: You're welcome!