# How to add Spheres[] sequentially from the surface of preexisting spheres?

Tags: random, geometry, rotation

I'd like to connect many spheres, by adding a new sphere at some point that's sitting on the surface of a previous sphere. How could we do this?

Suppose I have a unit sphere and a point on it:

```
myShpere1=Sphere[];
myPoint1=SpherePoints[1];
Graphics3D[{myShpere1, Point[myPoint1]}]
```

[image]

How can we add a second sphere who's surface is touching the previous one at the random point, then a third sphere on a random point of the second sphere, and so on? (for any number of spheres, always choosing a new random point). On a related issue, do spheres have an orientation in MMA, [as ellipsoids do](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138154/how-to-rotate-3d-ellipsoid-with-built-in-functions)? If so, how do we get the "vector/axis" of orientation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
spheres = Sphere[#, 1] & /@ NestList[
  With[{rp = RandomPoint[Sphere[#, 1]]}, 2 rp - #] &, {0, 0, 0}, 5];
```

[image: chained spheres]

If you need the spheres to be self avoiding, then you could look into [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/170904/create-a-random-polymer-chain).

All spheres are oriented upward.

Comment: You don't need to map `Sphere[]`, since it can support multiple centers if the radius is fixed: `Graphics3D[Sphere[NestList[With[{rp = RandomPoint[Sphere[#, 1]]}, 2 rp - #] &, {0, 0, 0}, 5], 1]]`

Answer (score 4):

`NestList` as in flinty's answer is a bit overkill. You can simply use `Accumulate` like this:

```
Graphics3D@Sphere@Accumulate[2 RandomPoint[Sphere[], 5]]
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Very cool! From @flinty answer I was able to get the coordinates of the points of sphere-sphere contact from the `NestList`. How could I get this info from your answer?

Comment: @TumbiSapichu That's a great question for you to figure out, I think, to make sure that you truly understand the solution. It's not difficult.

Comment: Ah, I see everything to the right of the accumulate is the points, the rest is just the plotting. I've just never used `Accumulate` so I though it'd do something weird. Thanks!