# How would you efficiently implement BinListsBy?

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, gathering

Let's say I have a list like this:

```
data = {{21, "Alice"}, {27, "Bob"}, {22, "Charles"}, {34, "Dora"}, {75, "Eliza"}}
```

containing ages and names of persons. What I would like is a list of e.g. 10-year age brackets, containing a list of *{age,name}*-pairs:

```
{
  {{21, "Alice"}, {27, "Bob"}, {22, "Charles"}}, (* 20-30 years *)
  {{34, "Dora"}}, (* 30-40 years *)
  {}, (* 40-50 years *)
  {}, (* 50-60 years *)
  {}, (* 60-70 years *)
  {{75, "Eliza"}} (* 70-80 years *)
}
```

`GatherBy[data, Floor[First[#]/10]&]` is close, but it leaves out empty bins.

`BinLists[data[[All, 1]], 10]` is also similar, but it only returns the list of ages, I can't get it to include the names as well.

Ideally, I'd like to have a function with similar syntax and performance to `BinLists`, i.e.: `binListsBy[data, {10,70,10}, First]`. And the function should be fast, because I'm going to use it on millions of entries (pixels of an image, in fact).

(Following [Mr.Wizard's meta discussion](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/what-are-the-qualities-of-a-good-question), I'm not going to add "what have I tried" in my question - I'm really looking for better ideas, or maybe even a built-in function I haven't noticed. Instead I'll post my attempts as an answer.)

Comment: I think question is a duplicate as it seems very familiar, yet I'm too tired to find the original right now.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/33153/862)?

Comment: @Simon It very well could be, though in my memory it is/was a little different.  Thanks for finding that.  There are probably several questions like this around.

Comment: [(19357)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19357) is also related; despite my having the Accepted answer there jVincent posted the better method, which used priming of `Tally` much as my answer here does with `GatherBy`.

Comment: What kind of input data will you use it on precisely?  Specifically: what opportunities are there to use packed arrays?

Comment: @Szabolcs: My actual purpose is to create a "weighted histogram", of e.g. gradient orientations, weighted by gradient strength of every pixel in an image. As in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23602/rotate-a-grid-made-up-of-lines-so-that-it-aligns-with-the-xy-axes/23625#23625. So yes, the data will probably be packed

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3981/5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fear this question is a duplicate, but it's faster for me to answer than find the original (I briefly tried).

```
fn[data_, {m_, M_}, step_] :=
 Rest /@ GatherBy[Join[List /@ Range[m, M, step], data], Quotient[First@#, step] &]

fn[data, {20, 70}, 10] // Column
```

> ```
> {{21, "Alice"}, {27, "Bob"}, {22, "Charles"}}
> {{34, "Dora"}}
> {}
> {}
> {}
> {{75, "Eliza"}}
> ```

If you want the range (`m`, `M`) automatic that's a simple substitution.  (Let me know.)

This is not written for ultimate speed but it should be pretty fast.

---

This is somewhat faster on your (packed) `randomData`; it uses a post-processing approach to zero-fill the `GatherBy` result.

*Edit: now significantly faster.*

```
fn2[data_, {m_, M_}, step_] :=
  Rest /@ GatherBy[
    Join[
      {{#}} & /@ Range[m, M, step],
      GatherBy[data, #[[1]] ~Quotient~ step &]
     ],
    #[[1, 1]] ~Quotient~ step &
  ] // Replace[#, {x_List} :> x, 1] &
```

Answer (score 9):

This is my current version:

```
Clear[binSpecToIndexFn, binSpecToRange, binListsBy]

(* takes a "bin specification", returns a function that converts a 
   value to a bin index *)
binSpecToIndexFn[{low_, high_, step_}] := Floor[(# - low)/step] &
binSpecToIndexFn[step_] := Floor[#/step] &

(* takes a bin specification and data, returns a range of bin indices *)
binSpecToRange[bspec : {low_, high_, step_}, data_] := 
 Range @@ binSpecToIndexFn[bspec] /@ {low, high}
binSpecToRange[bspec_, data_] := 
 Range @@ Through[{Min, Max}[binSpecToIndexFn[bspec] /@ data]]

binListsBy[data_, bspec_, fn_] := Module[{binIndexFn, gathered},
  binIndexFn = binSpecToIndexFn[bspec];
  gathered = GatherBy[data, binIndexFn[fn[#]] &];
  binSpecToRange[bspec, fn /@ data] /. 
   Flatten[{binIndexFn[fn[#[[1]]]] -> # & /@ 
      gathered, _?IntegerQ -> {}}]]
```

I'm not particularly happy that I had to reinvent the "bin specification" logic that has to be somewhere in MMA (`Histogram`, `BinCounts`, `BinLists` all share the same logic). Also, the range/index replacement rules logic seems unnecessarily complex for such a simple task, but I couldn't come up with something simpler.

Usage:

```
data = {{21, "Alice"}, {27, "Bob"}, {22, "Charles"}, {34, "Dora"}, {75, "Eliza"}};
binListsBy[data, 10, First]
```

---

**Timing:**

Baseline: `BinLists`

```
randomData = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10000000, 2}];
BinLists[randomData[[All, 1]], 10]; // Timing
```

> 0.593 s

@Mr. Wizard's version:

```
fn2[data_, {m_, M_}, step_, fn_] := 
 Rest /@ GatherBy[
    Join[{{#}} & /@ Range[m, M, step], 
     GatherBy[data, fn[#]~Quotient~step &]], #[[1, 1]]~Quotient~
      step &] // Replace[#, {x_List} :> x, 1] &

fn2[randomData, {0, 1}, 0.1, First]; // Timing
```

> 0.749 s

My original version

```
binListsBy[randomData, .1, First]; // Timing
```

> 1.279 s

@Murta's version:

```
binListByMurta[randomData, {0, 1, .1}, 1, First]; // Timing
```

> 7.22 s

@Kuba's version (using my `binSpecTo*`-Heplers)

```
binListsByKuba[data_, bspec_, fn_] := Module[{binIndexFn},
  binIndexFn = binSpecToIndexFn[bspec];
  Last@Reap[Scan[Sow[#, binIndexFn[fn[#]]] &, data], 
    binSpecToRange[bspec, fn /@ data]]]
binListsByKuba[randomData, .1, First]; // Timing
```

> 26.6 s

So @Mr. Wizard's version is the fastest by a large margin. And some day, I will understand how it works...

Comment: Perhaps ``BinningUtilities`BinCutOffs[fn /@ data, bspec]`` would help... It gives cut-offs instead of indices, though.

Comment: Are you going to add my functions to your timings?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: I'm trying to, but I honestly don't understand it well enough. To compare the timings, the function should take a function parameter, like the other versions. Yours (I think?) always gathers by the first subelement, which may or may not be faster than calling a user-supplied function.

Answer (score 6):

I miss a native implementation of this. Here's how I do this:

```
binListBy[data_List,binSize_,binIndex_Integer,aggrateFunctions_,nullValue_:Null]:=Module[{max,min},
    {min,max}=Floor[Through@{Min,Max}@data[[All,binIndex]],binSize];
    binListBy[data,{min,max,binSize},binIndex,aggrateFunctions,nullValue]
]

binListBy[data_List,{min_,max_,binSize_},binIndex_Integer,aggrateFunctions_,nullValue_:Null]:=
  Module[{intervals,findInterval,binRule},

    intervals=Partition[Range[min,max+binSize,binSize],2,1];
    findInterval={Floor[#,binSize],Floor[#,binSize]+binSize}&;
    binRule=findInterval@#[[1,binIndex]] -> {findInterval@#[[1,binIndex]],aggrateFunctions@Transpose@#}&/@GatherBy[data,findInterval[#[[binIndex]]]&];

    binRule=Dispatch@Join[binRule,{{a_,b_}:> {{a,b},nullValue}}];
    intervals/.binRule
]
```

Testing question data:
binListBy[data, 10, 1, Last]

> {{{20,30},{Alice,Bob,Charles}},{{30,40},{Dora}},{{40,50},Null},{{50,60},Null},{{60,70},Null},{{70,80},{Eliza}}}

Another test:

```
test = RandomInteger[{20,100}, {100, 2}];
binedList=binListBy[test,20,1,Total[#[[2]]]&,0]
```

Answer (score 4):

This probably won't be the fastest but worth to add:

```
Last @ Reap[Scan[Sow[#, Floor[#[[ 1]]/10]] &, data], 
            Range[2, 7]]
```

> ```
> {{ {{21, "Alice"}, {27, "Bob"}, {22, "Charles"}}}, 
>    {{{34, "Dora"}}}, 
>    {},
>    {},
>    {},
>    {{{75, "Eliza"}}
> }}
> ```

So at the end:

```
ClearAll[mybin];
mybin[data_, {min_, max_, dx_: 1}] := Reap[Scan[Sow[#, Floor[#[[1]]/dx]] &, data], 
                                           Range[Floor[min/dx], Floor[max/dx]]][[ 2]]
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple alternative:

```
data = {{21, "Alice"}, {27, "Bob"}, {22, "Charles"}, {34, "Dora"}, {75, "Eliza"}};

result = Sort /@ 
   GatherBy[
    Join[Transpose[{Range[0, 100, 10], Table[" ", {11}]}], data], 
    Floor[First[#]/10] &] // TableForm

TableForm[result, TableSpacing -> {2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: The OP's example does not sort the values in the output lists; that may not be desired.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard this may or may not be done (see my update)

Comment: Why not simply use this?: `result = GatherBy[Join[Transpose[{Range[0, 100, 10], Table[" ", {11}]}], data], Floor[First[#]/10] &];`  That is essentially what I did in my answer (`fn`).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - I didn't pretend to give a "better" answer but just wanted to know how I would write this myself. If you consider my answer as a duplicate of yours, please let me know and I delete it.

Comment: No, I didn't meant to imply that, and please do not think you are not welcome to post an answer unless you claim it is "better."  Rather I was trying to guide or refine the answer you gave.  I like the visual presentation but I didn't vote for the answer because I'm not sure it's helpful to the OP.  Anyway, my apologies for stepping on your toes.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard is right, I'm not looking for a "presentation" solution, but one where I can process the resulting lists further. I wouldn't mind modifying the code to do that, but even if I strip away the strings and `TableForm`'s, it adds a number to each result list, and I'm not sure if it will always be the first element (so I can remove it easily)